# Make the compiler tell which methods are not concrete instead of erroring 'invalid new-expression of abstract class type'

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual-functions

Every time I add a non-concrete virtual method to an abstract class, the compiler gives unuseful error `invalid new-expression of abstract class type '...'` on all the classes that derives from that abstract class, and then I need to do `git diff` to search for the new method I added earlier, or look for the note in GCC's errors. (there can be days difference between adding the method, and compiling)

Can I specify in C++ that a class must be concrete (and if it's not tell the cause/missing-method)?

Comment: Can you clarify what "look for the note in GCC's errors" means, and in particular, why is doing that not what you want? A compiler error report consists of all messages related to that error, not just the single line saying "error."

Comment: [Modern compilers emit a rather explicit message](https://godbolt.org/g/rZsYMC)...

Comment: @Angew because lots of files are compiled at once (it's a makefile), and GCC writes all kind of stuff about them. Searching for the error, and reading the lines below consumes lots of time, the task I said in the question happens a lot.

Comment: @VTT See my comment.

Comment: *"there can be days difference between adding the method, and compiling"* - Either I completely misunderstand what you mean, or you have one heck of an unusual development routine.

Comment: Question title asks "Make the compiler tell which methods are not concrete", compilers do this by printing base class and method that are not implemented making this class abstract.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. All compilers which I have tested gives a error message like "because the following methods are abstract"... So please use a up to date compiler!

Comment: The problem is that there can be 20 missing member functions, so they simply wouldn't fit into a single error message. The thing is, the compiler *is* telling you the missing function(s). You just have to read its entire output.

Comment: @Angew if I specify that the class is concrete, then regardless if I do new, then the compiler should make an error for each missing member that prevents the class to be concrete, it sounds reasonable for me.

Comment: @VTT I said in my question that my compiler does that, it's just not comfortable searching these notes in a long output log.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky How will changing the format from "note" to "error" make it more comfortable?

Comment: @Angew I grep "error: ". (greping a note will result in giving me 50% of the output)

Comment: Then grep "following virtual functions are pure" or something not so generic... Also this implies that you are getting huge amount of errors so you should compile more often fixing problems immediately and preventing them from piling up.

Comment: We either don't understand you or there is something wrong with the way you are doing this. This really shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: or grep with `-B -A -C -n` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines

Comment: @VTT it's warnings, not errors. (the people I cooperate with, don't care about the existence of them)

Comment: @bolov didn't want this, but I will live with this for the moment.

Comment: You could be interested in my [question about telling GCC diagnostics apart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21905742/1782465), there could be some solution for you in there.

Comment: then create a small script that parses the error messages/logs and prints you just the information you want: classes/methods in question. You can format this output to your heart's delight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question at hand:

> Can I specify in C++ that a class must be concrete (and if it's not tell the cause/missing-method)?

C++ has no explicit *abstract* or *concrete* classes. These concepts are implicit in the language. *Abstract* is implied by the presence (either in the class itself or inherited) of one or more pure virtual member functions, and *concrete* by the absence of such functions.

This is exactly how the C++ standard defines an *abstract* class (§13.4/2)

> [class.abstract]
>
> An abstract class is a class that can be used only as a base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it. **A class is abstract if it has at least one pure virtual function**.

There's no keyword such as Java's `abstract`, for example, in C++.

Compiler error messages are the standard place where you can catch errors such as the attempt to instantiate a class that still has pure virtual member functions.